# Can I dynamically place a breakpoint in the event of an exception in Ruby?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, ruby-debug, conditional-breakpoint, dbstop

I'd like to be able to set conditional breakpoints in ruby-debug, where the condition is "An exception was thrown."

What I'd like is the ability to land on a breakpoint whenever an exception is thrown on that line (a la MATLAB's ultra-convenient *dbstop if error* option [illustrated here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/04/28/matlab-basics-using-dbstop-if-error/)).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the example you provided "debugger if XXXXX" should work fine.

if the statement debugger works for you, there is no reason

if some_condition
  debugger
end

would not, and that is basically what your line does.  I do this all the time and it works fine.

for breaking on exceptions, you can override the class Exception and put the debugger statement in the initializer method.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the prompt response. I must have been doing something weird the last time I tried that. I've revised my question to be just the "debugger if an exception is raised" feature.